# Service Location Protocol (SLP) binding in Python

Tags: python, service-discovery, slp

Is there a library for implementing a [Service Location Protocol](http://www.openslp.org/) (SLP) client in Python?

Comment: I cannot understand this policy of StackOverflow. I find the question useful, and the answers are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to come by I'm afraid. I have however found an [old wrapper for OpenSLP](http://openslp.svn.sourceforge.net):

It is located under trunc/misc/python

Answer (score 1):

pyslp: [Service Location Protocol, Version 2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyslp)

- SLP Server;
- SLP Client.

> pip install pyslp